# How do I deal with pagination when I have so many pages to paginate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

I have known so far that paginate only links different pages. This can work very well when I have limited number of pages / post to display. But what if I have 30 or more pages to paginate? Isn't it a bad idea to create different pages and link them with the paginate? With this approach it becomes hard to maintain the consistency of the layout of the pages while having so many pages to link. Is there any better design where I can have only one page to display (lets call it the parent page) and when clicking the navigation it should only brings only the contents (from the child pages) and replace it with the previous one in the parent page?
If I was failed to make you understand what I want to say, consider the following situation.

HTML:

```
<div class="pagination">
  <a href="index/story0.html">&laquo;</a>
  <a href="index/story1.html">1</a>
  <a href="index/story2.html" class="active">2</a>
  <a href="index/story3.html">3</a>
  <a href="index/story4.html">4</a>
  <a href="index/story5.html">5</a>
  <a href="index/story6.html">6</a>
  <a href="index/story7.html">&raquo;</a>
</div>
```

In the method above, I will have to create 7 different pages to link with. How come that I create 7 different html pages for 7 different stories with lots duplicate contents? 
Could you please suggest me a better practice?
Please see the photo below to know what kind of page I am intending to build.[image]

Comment: The solution you're looking for can see solved using a template engine, take a look at handlebars.js or lodash templates.

You could also use plain javascript but you do not need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: lleon, Thanks, I got an idea, seems its bit complicated. I am wondering lots of modern webpages have this pagination. Then how does the developer solve this problem ? Do they also install handelbars.js or lodash template? Which approach do you follow  lleon?

Comment: Most of modern web apps are build on top of big front end frameworks, like Angular, React or Vue, I'd say these three are the most popular right now. I suggested you handlebars beacause it's a simple solution for the question you've asked, but in real apps you'll probably would want to use one of the mentioned frameworks

Comment: I've edited my answer with more useful information

Answer (score 0):

Well you're trying to build something complex actually.

I assume it's a personal project and you do not want to use a blog framework like Wordpress.

I also don't know what your programming background is but you seem to be a beginner (sorry if I'm mistaken).

For a blog website you'll need to persist the blog posts, the comments and that kind of data, your app will need to database and backend applicaction (php or nodejs + express may be the easiest one to setup) that serves the data.

For the frontend development you should use one of the framework already mentioned (Vue seems the easiest to learn) or you just can rely on server side rendering.

I've found this [(very, very) basic example](http://programanddesign.com/php/create-a-blog-in-30-minutes-without-a-framework) (I'm not the author and I am not related with him), this is just a demo, a real world app would require more time and effort and it would probably be built on top of one big framework (backend and frontend)

Here is a list of technologies you could take a look avaluate them an choose the one that fit your needs.

First of all [Wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/), it's a blog framework, you probably wont need to make any kind of backend development but you'll need to do some frontend development if you want to apply your custom theme.

If want to build a blog site from the scratch you'd probably want to learn one these technologies

**Backend development frameworks:**

- Python -> [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/start/)
- Ruby -> [Ruby on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)
- PHP -> [Laravel](https://laravel.com/)
- Node -> [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/)

**Frontend development frameworks:**

- [Angular](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)
- [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html)
- [Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/)
- [Ember](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/getting-started/quick-start/)
- [MarionetteJS](https://marionettejs.com/)

**Database:**

- [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/what-is-mongodb)
- [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/)

---

***Previous answer***

Here is a pure javascript implementation but as I said in the comment it would be better is you use a template engine like [handlebars.js](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/)

```js
var pageElement = document.querySelector('.pagination');
var totalPages = 8;
var pageText = ''

for (var currentPage = 0; currentPage < totalPages; currentPage += 1) {
    var content = currentPage;
    
    if (currentPage === 0) {
      content = '&laquo;';
    } else if (currentPage === totalPages - 1) {
      content = '&raquo';
    }
    
    
    pageText += '<a href="index/story' + currentPage + '.html">' + content + '</a>\n';

}
pageElement.innerHTML = pageText;
```

```html
<div class="pagination">
</div>
```

Comment: lleon, thnaks for your answer. By the way I have found an interesting example: http://listjs.com/examples/pagination/ what do you think about this?

Comment: It's a clean plugin that do what you want. But keep in mind that the data being paginated lives sin the same html page not in separated pages like your example. I do not know what are trying to build or what kind of data you want to paginate. The ideal solution would be to fetch the data when you click the link. I could suggest you more or better alternatives if I knew more about the problem.

Comment: lleon, I am going to build a blogging site, where I would like to navigate through different blog posts / articles. I don't know its good idea to have only one page and storing all the posts inside that like this example or creating different pages will be good idea? Please look my update (image) I have attached.